# Grouping by a Concat Column problem SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, group-by, concatenation, aggregate-functions

I am trying to group by the results of the query with a `concat` column, but I am stuck with it.

So this is my query:

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT (a.athleteLastName, ', ', a.athleteFirstName, ' (', a.athletePosition, ')') AS "Athlete",
    COUNT(M.awardName) AS "Number of Awards Won" 
FROM 
    award m
FULL OUTER JOIN 
    winner w ON m.awardId = w.awardId
FULL OUTER JOIN  
    athlete a ON w.athleteId = a.athleteId
GROUP BY 
    M.awardId, athleteLastName, a.athleteFirstName,a.athletePosition
ORDER BY 
    M.awardId DESC, Athlete;
```

This is the result:

```
Trout, Mike (OF)    1
Arenado, Nolan (3B) 4
Arenado, Nolan (3B) 7
Trout, Mike (OF)    3
```

But I want to group the count of awards by the player, and it should end like this:

```
Arenado, Nolan (3B) 13
Trout, Mike (OF)    4
```

Comment: Where does 13 come from with 4 & 7

Comment: In Nolan Arenado case, 4 & 7 are the number of awards he earned on a season

Comment: So every athlete is a winner with an award? Your use of FULL JOIN implies that is not a requirement but your result suggests your sample data is not adequate to test your code completely.

Answer (score 0):

How can `Arenado, Nolan (3B)` becomes `13`?  If simply summing up the awards, you can use subquery and can try this:

```
select "Athlete", sum("Number of Awards Won") as awards
from
(SELECT CONCAT (a.athleteLastName, ', ',a.athleteFirstName,' (',a.athletePosition,')') AS "Athlete" ,count(M.awardName) AS "Number of Awards Won" FROM award m
        FULL OUTER JOIN winner w ON m.awardId = w.awardId
        FULL OUTER JOIN  athlete a ON w.athleteId = a.athleteId
        GROUP BY M.awardId, athleteLastName, a.athleteFirstName,a.athletePosition
        ORDER BY M.awardId DESC, Athlete )  as a group by 1;
```